# ¿Cómo se dice "giftee" en español?

Tags: traducción, uso-de-palabras, selección-de-palabras, vocabulario, significado

Yo estoy intentando usar BING TRANSLATE sin éxito.  Ejemplo:

Toda buena dádiva y todo don perfecto es de lo alto, que desciende del Padre de las luces, en el cual no hay mudanza, ni sombra de variación.

"Yo soy un giftee". ¿Cuál es la palabra para "giftee"?

> The recipient of a gift.
>
> ‘certificates can be sent to you or directly to the **giftee**’
>
> fuente: https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/giftee

Comment: ¿[Recipiente](http://dle.rae.es/?w=recipiente)?

Comment: It is hard to see any word in the quote which might correspond to giftee can you clarify?

Comment: A giftee is "One who receives a gift." I don't think that there is a word for this in Spanish (although others might prove me wrong). So the translation should not use the verb _ser_ (like in I am/ I have this property or quality" You would simply translate as "yo **he recibido** un regalo"

Comment: @RosieM.Banks, no son malas opciones (como por ejemplo perceptor, agasajado, destinatario, ...) pero no sé sin en los términos va implícito que se recibe un *regalo*, y no otra cosa, como parece ser el caso en _giftee_. A mi de momento la que más me convence es [obsequiado](https://dle.rae.es/?id=QoiYYE9) o [donatario](https://dle.rae.es/?id=E7xI90n)

Comment: Gracias por su buena respuesta.

Answer (score 7):

The challenge here could be what we want to consider a gift, and what is the appropriate context to choose from a term over another. I could not find in Spanish a term describing "The recipient of a **gift** - and just a *gift*".

Instead of using the verb *ser* (like in "I am gifted") you would say in Spanish

> He recibido un regalo

or maybe

> He recibido un don

Which could be better for you context since a [don](https://dle.rae.es/?id=E7db2Hk%7CE7fKGDe) is

> 1. m. Dádiva, presente o regalo.
> 2. m. Gracia especial o habilidad para hacer algo.

Which could open another possibility (that does not apply to your context) since "I am gifted" could be translated as "he recibido un regalo/don" but also as "tengo un don" (I have a special gift/talent for this).

Other "honorable mentions" for word which can imply "One who receives a gift." could be

- [Obsequiado](https://dle.rae.es/?id=QoiYYE9)

  > Agasajar a alguien con atenciones, servicios o regalos.
- [donatario](https://dle.rae.es/?id=E7xI90n) (which would apply more in a legal context)

  > 1. m. y f. Persona a quien se hace la donación.
- [Agraciado](https://dle.rae.es/?id=17ShAGE) Even if the dictionary entries don't seem to apply, the meanings of [agraciar](https://dle.rae.es/?id=17VtGWm) make it possible that you say

  > He sido **agraciado**  <sub>I have been granted a grace/gift</sub>

and you convey that you received "gracia divina" (divine grace) or you have been granted *something* (a [*gracia*](https://dle.rae.es/?id=JOCFpLb)/grace), which would convey very well your message and apply to your context.

Comment: Me gusta especialmente _obsequiado_, pues _agraciado_ solemos usarlo para cosas más aleatorias como la lotería.

Comment: Gracias por su respuesta!

Comment: @JckGutknecht De nada. Por cierto, para esta, y otras preguntas que tienes en el stack, no olvides **aceptar una respuesta** de entre las sugeridas. Eso ayuda a la comunidad a saber que hemos proporcionado una respuesta que te ayuda (sea o no sea la más votada). De [tour] "Accepting [an answer] doesn't mean it's the best answer, it just means that it worked for the person who asked."

Answer (score 4):

Si la pregunta consiste en cuál es la traducción de:

- *I am a giftee*.

en un contexto general, no legal, me inclinaría por:

- Soy un **beneficiario** (generalmente por haber recibido algo material).
- Soy un **agraciado / favorecido** (generalmente por haber recibido algo inmaterial).

No me parece que "obsequiado" sea una traducción correcta para referirse al receptor de un obsequio. En el contexto de un festejo, podemos hablar de "agasajado".

En un contexto religioso, donde el obsequio sería un talento o una gracia divina, podemos decir:

- Estoy **bendecido** (por Dios). (O inclusive: Soy un **elegido**.)

Comment: Gracias por su respuesta!

Answer (score 0):

Yo diría:

> Yo soy el que recibió el regalo.

O más simplemente:

> Soy el recipiente de un regalo.

Esta palabra "giftee" tiene mucho que ver con la cultura angloparlante y por eso un poco difícil de traducir a una palabra en el castellano.

Comment: Gracias por su respuesta.